# How to download the executable program from Visual Studio Team Services for People

Tags: azure-devops

In git-hub i noticed that we can download the final programs from the repository. Can we do the same in visual studio team services? Also can i allow users to file bugs for my program using VSTS?. 
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can download the project using Download zip option when you click on the repo.

Refer the image.

[image]

You can develop your own program using VSTS rest APIs to file bugs.
Reference: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items

Comment: Can i other people other than my team to download the file.  i mean public.

Comment: only members of that team project has the access.